# Is there a rigorous way to view ML activation functions?

Tags: matrices, notation

A common activation function in Machine Learning is ReLU, defined as:
$$
ReLU: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
ReLU(x) := \begin{cases}
0 \mbox{ if } x < 0\\
x \mbox{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

However, people in ML always like to apply functions componentwise to column matrices of real numbers. For example, they will write:

$ReLU(\begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

Is there a way to formalize this? For example, by defining a Matrix as some sort of container object, and allowing functions to operate on elements of containers? Or is the present mathematical definition of a function too strict already, and this will forever remain an abuse of notation? (i.e what people mean is that $ReLU$ is a function from column matrices to column matrices?)

Comment: Just write that and say "where the function is applied [component-wise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise#Componentwise_operations)" or "element-wise," and you will be understood.

Comment: An activation function is a non-linear function (as far as I understand, neural networks would basically be single matrices otherwise), and so you shouldn't expect to be able to write down the activation function as a matrix multiplication. In full generality, an activation function is just some map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, but is commonly given by an application of some $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ componentwise, i.e. $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (g(x_1), \ldots, g(x_n))$.

Comment: @angryavian right, so there is no rigorous way to view it, preserving the mathematical definition of function? The question was not asking for how to write it.

Comment: Letting "ReLU" refer to *both* the original function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as well as a component-wise function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ may be an "abuse of notation," but I do not see this as something non-rigorous. But I suppose this is subjective. If I were you I would not spend too much time worrying about this.